Determining if a Matrix is Diagonalizable and the Geometric and Algebraic Multiplicity of Eigenvalues

I am provided the matrix
$$ 
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & -2 & 4 
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
and asked to determine the algebraic and geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalues. I am also asked if it is diagonalizable, and to find the diagonalization if so.

Below I will explain the steps I attempted explaining when necessary.
I began by determining the characteristic equation which I know can be found with $\det(A - \lambda \mathbb{I}_n)$ where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix. Setting this up I got:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
3-\lambda & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1-\lambda & 1 \\
-2 & -2 & 4-\lambda \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
I calculated the determinant using cofactor expansion and after simplifying was left with the characteristic equation:
$$
(3 - \lambda)(\lambda^2 - 5\lambda + 6) = 0
$$
This gives us the eigenvalues, $\lambda = 3$ with a multiplicity of $2$ and $\lambda = 2$ with a multiplicity of $1$. From here I continued by solving for the eigenvectors.
$$
A-3\Bbb I_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & -2 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix} -
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -2 & 1 \\
-2 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
2 & -2 & 1 \\
-2 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
After solving the linear system I got an eigenvector of $\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$. I did the same process for $2$. Of course I used $A-2\Bbb I_3$ since the eigenvalue was $2$.
I found the eigenvector to be $\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$.
I answered this question by saying the $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ is not diagonalizable because the number of eigenvectors must be equal to $n$ but in this scenario we only have $2$ eigenvectors.

Question:
Is this correct? It feels as if I am missing something, and I am not sure how geometric multiplicity differs from algebraic multiplicity in this scenario.

Welcome to MSE. I took the liberty of making a few changes so that your post appears like many MSE posts. You can understand the changes to be made via the ‘Edit’ command.

Oh, sorry. I looked too quickly at the last two rows. My mistake.

You aren’t missing anything other than “linearly independent” in front of your “eigenvectors.”

$A$ is diagonalizable if and only if for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is equal to the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$.
So you can check diagonalizability of $A$ using the above theorem.
